# Android Studio 3.6 hangs every time

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.6

Working with **android studio 3.6**.Freezing every time trying to make changes in designing part in design section.whenever trying to make changes in attributes section its **freezing** every time for hours and have to close android studio using task manager.Giving screen shot where its freezing.Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: It will resolve your issue please see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61223110/12386821